# Why isn't innerHTML call working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Link to my codepen:https://codepen.io/Kibitz/pen/PKdLma?editors=1111.

I'm running an ajax call that gets information from Wikipedia for results. Upon succeeding I have a `for` loop that adds the results to an array.

Currently, I just have one innerHTML statement to try and modify a `p` tag that starts as the word placeholder.
Eventually, I want to show ten results. Currently, the innerHTML call isn't modifying the placeholder word.

This is a snippet of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            res[i] = data[1][i];
        }
        console.log(res);
        document.getElementById("results1").innerHTML = res[0];
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {
        console.log('here');
        alert("error");
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("complete");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you replace line

```
document.getElementById("results1").innerHTML =res[0];
```

with

```
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML =res[0];
```